# How do I declare a user defined function in OMNet++?

Tags: omnet++

I have declared a function in the c++ file as stated in the documentation and called it in the .ned file. But it gives the following error.

```
error:expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token Define_Function(dijkstra, 1);
```

The following is my c++ file.

```
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "cdelaychannel.h"

Define_Function(dijkstra, 1);
double dijkstra(double start = 1){
....
....
}
```

In my network description file, I've called the function.

```
package myproject;

@license(LGPL);
dijkstra(1.0);
```

Why is it giving me the error?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a function for using it in NED files, you have to do it as described in [OMNeT++ Manual](http://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec301). An example could be the following:

```
static cNEDValue ned_foo(cComponent *context, cNEDValue argv[], int argc) 
  int a = (long) argv[0];   
  int b = (long) argv[1];   
  return a*b; 
}

Define_NED_Function(ned_foo,"int ned_foo(int a, int b)");
```